# Is there a way in SpringBoot to add default data for fields while the entity class is being created?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

This is My entity class, this represents the account which upadtes the accountBalance based on the transactions happen on one more entity,

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MainAccounts {
     @Id
        private Long id  ;
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        private LocalDate date
        private Double AccountBalance;
        
       
        public Double getAccountBalance() {
            return AccountBalance;
        }
        public void setAccountBalance(Double accountBalance) {
            AccountBalance = accountBalance;
        }
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public LocalDate getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
```

Once the entity is created, can i able to add default values to my accounts table,like this?

| id | date | accountBalance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 0.00 |

simply i dont want the table to have null values,when i invoke getId(), or getaccountBalance() methods

Comment: You can simply instantiate the Entity fields with default value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can set it thanks to @Column annotation.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values

```
To create a default value directly in the SQL table definition, we can use the @Column annotation and set its columnDefinition parameter:
```

```java
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default 'John Snow'")
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 25")
    private Integer age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PrePersist` from JPA.

```java
public class MainAccounts {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        this.accountBalance = 0.0;
        // any value setting before saving
    }

}
```

You might also want to visit `@PreUpdate` which is called before updating an managed entity.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set directly to the entity properties

```
private String name = "default";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider going through Stack Overflow's help section in order to know how to answer a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score -1):

you are using `@Data` already which means you don't need to write the getter and setter manually, because the Lombok will generate it in the background just use setDate(your date here), and apply the same concept on all the getters and setter methods,

**Note: if the date will represent the creation date you can use this annotation to set
above date variable `@CreationTimestamp`**

Comment: At the time of creation of an entity, getters and setter are not used. OP is asking how to add default values at the time of creation.